# how can I retrieve value of calendar in row in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyQ7z.jpg)I tried to get the value of all rows in a table with the given code.
But there is a calendar in the first cell of the first row.

The code works as expected but it doesn't retrieve calendar value at all. It just skips the calendar, gets the value of the first row and then all the rows in the table.

How can I write code to get the value of the Calendar as well the rest of the rows in the table?

```java
String searchResultXpath = "//*[@id='accountTable']/table/tbody/tr";
List<WebElement> searchRuslt  = driver.findElements(By.xpath(searchResultXpath);
        
int resultSize = searchResul.size();
        
for (int i=0; i<resultSize; i++ ){
    System.out.println(searchResult.get(i).getText());
}
```

Comment: thank you James.

Comment: Please share html of first row and calendar?

Comment: it's an Enterprise application. so you will not able to log in I have just uploaded a pic of it. just click on the "Enter image description here"  link. you will be able to see it.

Comment: You can paste html in your question so I can try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add a condition to get the cell value for the first row.

```
for (int i=0; i<resultSize; i++ ){
    if(i==0){
       System.out.println(searchResult.get(i).findElement(By.tagName("td")).getText());
    }
    System.out.println(searchResult.get(i).getText());
}
```

PS: This is just pseudo code. If you can share the snippet of html code, I might be able to help you better.